# DBeaver id column defaults to 1

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

Created a user table in DBeaver for Postgres DB. The `user_id` col is set to int. Manually entered `user_id` but when I refresh the table it resets all of 1.

[image]

1. Why is that?
2. How do I make this the Primary Key so that it auto numbers? Tried using Constraint to set `user_id` as the Primary Key but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL is to set the user_id column to be of type SERIAL or BIGSERIAL as these types are auto-incrementing integers.

If you are not using this table then you can create another table with the following SQL query in DBeaver SQL Editor:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    -- other columns...
);
```

Else you can alter this table

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD PRIMARY KEY (user_id);
```

While using GUI, you can refer to the official docs of DBeaver explaining all this process [Official Tutorial for DBeaver](https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/New-Table-Creation/)